# Maximum likelihood estimate of data

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

I have to find the maximum likelihood estimate of the parameter $\theta$ given the following data where $x$ is the observation from a discrete distribution and $f(x;\theta)$ is the probability mass function, $\theta\in\{1,2,3\}$.
$$
\begin{matrix}
x&f(x;1)&f(x;2)&f(x;3) \\
0&1/3&1/4&0 \\
1&1/3&1/4&0 \\
2&0&1/4&1/4 \\
3&1/6&1/4&1/2 \\
4&1/6&0&1/4
\end{matrix}
$$
I understand that for each observation, the maximum likelihood estimate is the value of $\theta$ that maximizes $f(x;\theta)$, but I don't understand how I can find the parameter value that maximizes the likelihood of the whole data.

Comment: Before doing the general case, lets start with a simple case. Suppose you only have one observation $x = 0$. Note that now both your sample and your parameter are discrete. To find the MLE, first you write down the likelihood, i.e. the (joint) pmf correspond to the observed sample. So in this case we have $\displaystyle f(x = 0; \theta = 1) = \frac {1} {3} > \frac {1} {4} = f(x = 0; \theta = 2)$ and thus the MLE is $\hat{\theta} = 1$. For the general case, the likelihood is $\displaystyle \prod_{i=0}^4 f(x = i; \theta)^{y_i}$ where $y_i$ is the number of observations taking value $i$.

Comment: With real data in hand, you can simply compute the likelihood for all $3$ possible values of $\theta$ and pick the one which maximize the likelihood. Without the actual observation, you may need some little manipulation to see how those $y_i$ affect your MLE.

Comment: @BGM: What do you suggest for $x = 2?$

Comment: @BruceET The MLE does not need to be unique. So, for single observation $x=2$ there are two MLE: $\hat\theta=2$ and $\hat\theta=3$.

Comment: @NCh: I know that, but wondered if OP would be puzzled.